# How to remove a row using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the bottom of the page a drop-down is listed for selecting new languages "Add Languages". If user select new language a row will generate.  If they don't need they can remove it. I have added a cross button and added a class name "removefile". How it works in my current code?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6a5d2v/12/)

**JS**

```
    //fake data for this test
var response = {
    availableLanguage: [{
        id: "1",
        language_id: "English",
        title_en: "USEnglish"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        title_en: "Hindi"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        title_en: "Arabi"
    }

    ]
}


var responseDB = {
    selectLanguageRankingTagId: [{
        id: "1",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "English",
        ranking: "2",
        title_en: "English"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "German",
        ranking: "3",
        title_en: "German"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        user_id: "11",
        language_id: "French",
        ranking: "4",
        title_en: "French"
    }

    ]
}


var $languagemodal = $('#languagemodal'); // get the modal and the dialog div
var $dialog = $languagemodal.find('.modal-dialog');

//$languagemodal.modal({show: true}); // just to show the modal for the demo

// get languages
//$.get("/tag/language", function(response){
        var optionLang = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < response.availableLanguage.length; i++) {
            engLangID  = response.availableLanguage[i].id;
            engLang    = response.availableLanguage[i].title_en;
            optionLang += '<option value="'+engLangID+'" data-language="'+engLang+'">'+engLang+'</option>';
        }

// load the modal content div
$dialog.html('<div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header "><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><h4 class="modal-title">Edit Languages</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="appendRow"></div></div><div class="modal-footer"><div class="row"><select class="form-control input-sm addMore"><option selected="selected">Add Language</option>' + optionLang + '</select></div><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div>');

// get the modal body we just added
var $modalBody = $dialog.find('.modal-body');

// loop over your data, you would have this in your $.get function 
$.each(responseDB.selectLanguageRankingTagId, function (i, item) {
    // make the row
    var $newRow = $('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><h4 style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 30px; margin:5px 0px; padding:4px 5px;">' + item.title_en + '</h4></div><div class="col-md-3" style="padding:5px;"><select class="form-control input-sm" id="' + item.id + '" data-item="' + item + '"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></div></div>')
    // set the select value
    $newRow.find('select').val(item.ranking);
    // add the row to the modal body
    $modalBody.append($newRow);

});

$(".modal-dialog").on('change', ".addMore", function(){
            var selected = $( this ).find(':selected');
            language       = selected.data('language');
            languageID     = selected.val();
            $( ".appendRow" ).append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><h4 style="background-color: lightgrey; border-radius: 10px; background-repeat: repeat; height: 30px; margin:5px 0px; padding:4px 5px;">'+language+'</h4></div><div class="col-md-3" style="padding:5px;"><select class="form-control input-sm"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removefile" data-removefile=""></span></div></div>');
        });    

 //});// get languages end
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="languagemodal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin: 54px 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there doesn't appear to be any 'X' in your code on the newly added rows? To do this you just need to traverse the DOM to find the closest `parent()` `div` and then `remove()` it

Comment: I have updated my demo now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/yjacy8gy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another delegated event handler for the `.removefile` element so that the parent `.row` is removed. Try this:

```
$('.modal-dialog').on('click', '.removefile', function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr6a5d2v/14/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".modal-dialog").on("click",".removefile",function(){
  jQuery(this).closest(".row").remove()
});
```

will remove the first parent element with class = row if an element with class = removefile is clicked

EDIT: my mistake in not testing before posting. in the chance you want to dynamically add elements later on, you have to attach the "click" event to a parent element that exists at the point the script is run, and delegate it to the proper dynamically created element

Comment: Don't forget that the `.removefile` elements are dynamically appended to the DOM, so you need to use a delegated event handler.